# Is this answer NAA or VLQ worthy?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts, not-an-answer, specific-answer

Before I flag, I wanted to confirm if this answer is worthy of either of those flags:

> [image]

The question is tagged with [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json). The OP wanted [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) code to solve the issue (as seen by the tags and the accepted answer) yet the OP of this answer posted a non [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) answer.

Now previously when I've flagged answers like this as NAA they've been declined because it is technically *an answer* (even though it isn't answering the question).

- Is the correct action here to flag?

  - If so which flag?
- or is the correct action to down-vote and move on?

Comment: Happened to me, yesterday. Q about Word; A for Excel. The Q-OP commented to the A-OP, who's reply was "Oh, yeah, I missed that." But didn't delete it. I flagged as LQ, which was rejected... <sigh>

Comment: @CindyMeister: VLQ isn't for technical inaccuracies, no matter how blatant.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, so I was reminded :-) Still, it would be useful to have a way to get rid of things so obviously not pertinent to the Q. And it's a shame to have to waste DV on things like that.

Comment: @CindyMeister: But is the downvote really wasted if you use it the way it was intended? :P

Comment: Mmm. There's some question in my mind how much use it is in a low-traffic tag (ms-word)... One, at the most, 2 DV is pretty much it, no matter what the content. Low quality posts are coming thick-and-fast. It would be *nice* to reach 20k at some point.

Comment: You're getting there.

Comment: @CindyMeister it sucks for those who are both curating and trying to reach a rep goal.

Comment: I'd think that this is an "orange", considering it's in the wrong language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- NAA: It *is* an answer. A wrong answer is still an answer.
- VLQ: It is not gibberish, or another language.

Neither of those flags apply.

If the answer is incorrect (wrong language), downvote and move on.
You could also comment on it if you feel adventurous.

Comment: I feel adventurous.

Comment: Should've seen that coming.

Comment: ...another (human-spoken) language? When I read that I said, "but it is another language! bash and JSONPath rather than PHP!" but then I (think I) got it.

Comment: @rene your humour is so dry... for a flower this is not healthy ;)

Comment: Exactly how useful is this answer on a scale from -1 to -1?

Comment: @JL2210: Do you have constructive feedback for this answer? Is it wrong? Do you disagree?

Comment: Yes: "Please write the answer in the language specified by the question. I personally don't know this language, but you might include an explanation, too."

Comment: Or you could just downvote a answer that's written in the wrong language, and move on.